# Play Animation key not working

Tags: animation

My play animation key isn't working, by that I mean its not playing the animation, but if I use the mouse to go through the animation frame by frame, then it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_642qpJ2pY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Render Settings set the End Frame to the last frame of the animation. Both numbers are 0 right now.

Comment: LOL, it's a weirdest case I saw lately :). BTW you may also change the *Start* and *End* frame settings @Josip Kladarić mentioned in a *Timeline*.